# Difference Between "Doesn't" and "Doesn't do"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

Is there any difference meaning between the below sentences?

According to me both the sentences give the idea of something that the system can't change automatically.

The system doesn't change this automatically.

&

The system doesn't do this change automatically.

Comment: Not a native English speaker, but "do changes" doesn't sound right to me. I think it should be "make changes."

Comment: "Do changes" is acceptable idiomatic English, so your choice depends upon where you intend to use the text. The first is a little less informal. There is a difference in meaning between the two: the first refers to a specific thing that can't be changed by the system, and the second does not.

Comment: @ P. E. Dant .... I have change my second sentence .... Now it can be specific.... Please let me know if Both my sentences are correct and have same meaning.

Comment: Now the first is better! _Do_ may not be a good verb here. Exactly what do want to explain or express? Use the [edit] link to add to your question. _"The system does not make this change automatically"_ is one possible option.

Answer (score 1):

**Not really.**

The first sentence is focused more on the change itself: for whatever reason, the transition between two states is not occurring. The second implies that there is some script or process which makes the change, and the system is not executing that process.

The difference is too subtle to matter without an explicit comparison though.